# Footer stuck in slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow, footer

I imported a wow slider to my webpage and now my footer is stuck in it. I tried using www.cssstickyfooter.com but it didn't work. I think is has something to do with the position element the slideshow uses. What would be causing this?

LIVE DEMO: http://epicureancateringaz.com/New/123

```
#footer{
position: relative;
margin-top: -100px;
height: 100px;
clear:both;
background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/footerback.png); 
}

#wowslider-container1 { 
zoom: 1; 
position: relative; 
max-width:1000px;
margin:9px auto 9px;
z-index:90;
border:9px solid #FFFFFF;
text-align:left; /* reset align=center */
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul{
position:relative;
width: 10000%; 
height:auto;
left:0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-spacing:0;
overflow: visible;
/*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inserted div#footer into your slideshow div. Just pull it out.